# cannot install MySQL-python on os x

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm trying to use MySQL database with Django on OS X 10.11.3 but when i try "pip install MySQL-python" it gives me this error:

```
Collecting MySQL-python   Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/0q/24f40xt52fg_xbjz5drz_m2r0000gn/T/pip-build-8ms1ni7b/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/private/var/folders/0q/24f40xt52fg_xbjz5drz_m2r0000gn/T/pip-build-8ms1ni7b/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

    ---------------------------------------- Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/0q/24f40xt52fg_xbjz5drz_m2r0000gn/T/pip-build-8ms1ni7b/MySQL-python
```

I tried installing ConfigParser and i have MySQL python connector installed on my system.

Here are my project details:

Django 1.9.2
Python 3.5
OS X 10.11.3
IDE PyCharm
Virtual Environment myvenv

I've searched internet and almost tried all methods to use MySQL with Django but i'm failing since hours. Please guide me with this

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to install the Python 2.X only driver on Python 3. The documentation recommends using mysqlclient:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers

The mysqlclient GitHub page with install instructions, including pre-requisites you may need:

https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i tried all of the steps you've mentioned in the answer and still no success. I can do migrations but if i open django console and try to run manage.py tasks it gives me this error upon start "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb' ".

Comment: Task i'm trying to execute is "from app.models import Artist newArtist=Artist(name="Hello1",year_formed=1985)"
and when i try executing the task it gives me 
"bash -cl "/usr/local/bin/python3.5 /Users/u/Library/Application\ Support/IntelliJIdea15/python/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py from app.models import Artist newArtist=Artist(name=\"Hello1\",year_formed=1985) /Users/u/IdeaProjects/App"
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('